# Multiple Criteria Filtering - Assigning Values for multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, filtering, vba

First off, I am not sure if what I want can be accomplished this way.
Please refer the image attached.

[image: Excel-Journals]

So there are 5 journal entries. 3 of them have a debit & a credit leg, 1 of them has 3 legs & 1 has 4 legs. Now, the 5 entries have a single unique "Voucher Name". 
What I exactly want is, if I filter "Cash" from Particulars column, by default in excel, I get the rows 2,4.
But what I want is when I filter "Cash", the entire journal entries with "Voucher code" which contains Cash must appear filtered. That is to say, rows 2,3,4,5 have to get filtered.

how do I do this?? 
PS: Pivot did not work.
I have data which is of 30000 line items.
SO manual work is not possible.

Comment: Have you changed your filter to is not equal to?  On the filter drop down, Text filters has an advanced section with "Does not equal."  From my understanding of your question, you want to exclude, which you would be able to with that available command, no VBA needed.

Comment: No Cyril. You got the question wrong. It's more like....1 voucher code is one single bunch. And when I filter any of the parts like "cash" "sales" or "bank", I need the entire bunch to be visible and not just "cash" "sales" or "bank" . For instance, when I filter for "TDS", the entire bunch, which is, row 6,7,8 shud be filtered records. And not just row 6 (by default).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Do you have any table indicating what is grouped?  This may help with creating an array, which you can create filters based on.

Comment: To add a little more transparency with my last comment... If you have a table, or a list, with the possible options, you can create arrays using those names.  Say on Sheet2, Range A1 to A5 is a list which you label "Money," you can call on that list, as an array, and the filter will apply for those items.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that will remove the data you're not interested in, but I couldn't get the default filtering to work (this will not "compress" the table).  Therefore, the data will still be scattered across 30,000 rows.  However, it will allow you to perform statistical analysis on the data of interest.

Assuming your original picture from above (copied in case it changes):

[image: Multiple filter criteria solution]

Put the **Particulars** value you would like to filter (*i.e. "Cash", "TDS", etc*) in `G1`.  Now put the following **array formula** (*ctrl+shift+enter*) in `G2`:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$8,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$8=$G$1,ROW($B$2:$B$8)-ROW($B$1),""),ROWS(G$2:G2)))
```

I obviously only used the first 8 rows of your data, so you'll have to expand.  Then, put this formula in `H2:L2` *(referencing `A2:E2`)*:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($G$2:$G$8,$C2)>0,A2,"")
```

Now, drag `H2:L2` down to the bottom of your dataset. When you supply one **Particular** in `G1` the formulas you dragged should only show that in which you're interested.  You'd have to expand on this concept for multiple **Particulars**, but I hope this answer will suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input :)